# Getting order number containing multiple item numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, join, case

I am working on a project in SQL Server where I need to find how many orders contain multiple products. For example there is an order number of 1 and it has multiple records 1 for style a and one for style b. I need to find how many orders contain both styles (a and b or a and c)

```
select distinct(ordernumber), Style
from table1
join table2 on join1 = join1
where Style in ('a','b','c')
order by ordernumber
```

I expect to bring the data into Excel to analyze it and see how many orders contain the combination I discussed.

```
ordernumber     style
1                 a
1                 b
2                 c
2                 a
```

I would like to see how many orders have multiple styles in them.

Comment: Please provide some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: my expected output would be to identify how many ordernumbers contain multiple styles, I would then bring that into Excel.

Comment: Hopefully you see why it is really difficult to write requirements. You refer to "combination I discussed", you refer to "both styles" (though you seem to skip the fact that <b, c> is a combination of the set <a, b, c>), and you also refer to "orders have multiple styles". In short, you're all over the place in defining what you want. That's a problem with using a very small sample and describing what you want by making very specific references to your sample. Does it matter if there are other styles or are you specifically looking for just those 2 combinations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find first the order number with multiple products, and then find details for all those order id. You can check the below script-

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.<Joining Column> = B.<Joining Column>    
WHERE A.ordernumber IN
( 
    --This query will return Order Numbers that have at least
    --2 style in the order details table
    SELECT C.ordernumber
    FROM table1 C
    INNER JOIN table2 D ON C.<Joining Column> = D.<Joining Column>
    WHERE Style IN ('a','b')
    GROUP BY C.ordernumber
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Style) = 2

    UNION

    SELECT C.ordernumber
    FROM table1 C
    INNER JOIN table2 D ON C.<Joining Column> = D.<Joining Column>
    WHERE Style IN ('a','C')
    GROUP BY C.ordernumber
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Style) = 2
)
```

Comment: I did that and then added Style IN ('a','b','c') to the original where outside the subquery.

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: Now I have to identify the number of orders with multiple distinct styles from the 3 provided. I might have to do that in Excel

Comment: you wants to see order id with either A&B OR A&C only?

Comment: Can you please check updated script. This will only return Order Number with A&B or A&C only.